# Dialogflow Get entities

Tags: google-api, dialogflow-es

I am trying to get entities either through a cURL request or using the nodejs SDK.

According to: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.entityTypes/get

I am supposed to pas in EntityType UUID(or name). Im not able to find my EntityType UUID through the console. Where can I get it

How should I achieve this through the nodejs SDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can use this endpoint to list all the UUIDs for all the entities: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.entityTypes/list